# What is the meaning of new List<string>(list)?

Tags: c#, list

[LeetCode 131](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning/description/)

This is a solution

```
public class Solution 
{
    public IList<IList<string>> Partition(string s) 
    {
        IList<IList<string>> res = new List<IList<string>>();
        CheckSubstring(new List<string>(), s, res, 0);
        return res;
    }

    void CheckSubstring(List<string> list, string s, IList<IList<string>> res, int startIndex)
    {
        if (startIndex == s.Length)
        {
            list = new List<string>(list);
            res.Add(list);
            return;
        }
        for (int end = startIndex; end < s.Length; end++)
        {
            string sub = s.Substring(startIndex, end - startIndex + 1);
            if (IsPalindrome(sub))
            {
                list.Add(sub);
                CheckSubstring(list, s, res, end + 1);
                list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    bool IsPalindrome(string s)
    {
        int left = 0, right = s.Length - 1;
        while (left < right)
        {
            if (s[left] != s[right])
            {
                return false;
            }
            left++;
            right--;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My question: what does the `list = new List<string>(list)` in `CheckSubstring` mean?

I think this line may means copy a new list, but it is already a list by itself, where is the meaning of making it a new list as it is?

Comment: Comment it out, it seems to be making a Shallow Copy, *but why?* I reckon its wrong.

Comment: when `if (startIndex == s.Length)` is true, you have an answer ready to be added in `res`. If you add `list` directly to `res`, then whenever original `list` is changed in other part of the code it will be changed in the `res` too. That's why with `new List<string>(list);` you create a new list with whatever is there in `list` and add to the `res`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))

Comment: parameter `list` is passed to the constructor which creates the copy of the data and store in a new list being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you have a piece of paper with a list of people's names on it. If you were to take a new piece of paper and copy the names onto it, then use that new list to do something, e.g. call all those people to ask for a donation and cross each one off that list after calling them, would this be confusing? I would think not. You have a new list with the same items that you can use for whatever purpose without affecting the original list. Tha's all that code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that `CheckSubstring` is a recursive function. The code is creating a copy of the list as it exists, and adding it to the results. The `list` parameter is modified, but the contents of the list that it references are not changed.

If the author had just written `res.Add(list)` without making a copy, then a reference to the list would have been written to the result, and any further changes to that list would be reflected in the final result. The author's intention is to take a snapshot of the list and add *that* to the result.

The author of that code, for reasons I can't fathom, decided to re-use the parameter as a temporary variable name. The result is code that's more difficult to understand than it has to be.

This code from the original:

```
list = new List<string>(list);
res.Add(list);
```

Is more clearly expressed as:

```
// Add a copy of the list to the results.
res.Add(new List<string>(list));
```

That avoids the troublesome re-assignment of the `list` parameter and more explicitly states exactly what's going on.